# Swiftui - Core Data many-to-many relationships access content

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm looking to build a little food app, with the following Core Data schema:
[CoreDataModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPX77.png)

On my view, I'm trying to access the content of a recipe, which contains ingredients:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RecipeDetailViewController: View {
    let recipe: RecipeEntity

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Preparation time:").bold()
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(recipe.recipePreparationTime)")
                    }

                    [...]

                    Text("Ingredients")

                    /// The following is my unsuccessful test:
                    let test = recipe.ingredientsInRecipe?.allObjects as? [IngredientInRecipeEntity]
                    ForEach(test!) { item in
                        if item.ingredient != nil {
                            if let debug = item.ingredient?.allObjects as? [IngredientEntity] {
                                ForEach(debug) { ingredient in
                                    Text("\(ingredient.name)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Text("No ingredient in this recipe!")
                        }

                        Text("Quantity: \(item.quantity)")
                    }

                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(recipe.nameUnwrapped)
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I access the content of an ingredient from the recipe?

Comment: It looks as though you're doing that, when you start with a recipe, then access `ingredientsInRecipe`, and then use `ingredient.name` to get the name of an ingredient. What else do you need that you're not already doing?

Comment: Your data model is wrong, a Recipe has many IngredientsInRecipe but an IngredientsInRecipe belongs to one Recipe and not many. And an IngredientsInRecipe has one Ingredient and an Ingredient can be used in many IngredientsInRecipe

Comment: Oh damn you're right, thanks for your answer!